# Google Analytics 4 Not Updating User Count in Real-Time for Chrome Extension Events

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, real-time-data

I have a chrome extension and I've applied Google analytics to that, like if a button is clicked, I perform this -

```
async function ga4(category, label, event) {
  chrome.storage.local.get("userId", function (data) {
      user_id = data.userId;
  });
  const params = {
      v: '2',
      tid: ga_tid,
      cid: user_id,
      en: event,
      'ep.event_category': category,
      'ep.event_label': label
  };
  const queryString = new URLSearchParams(params).toString();
  const url = `https://www.google-analytics.com/g/collect?${queryString}`;
  const options = { method: 'POST' };
  if(ga_tid){
    fetch(url, options);
  }
}
```

When i see users from audience in GA4 property, i see there are 38 users, but I do not get any demographic details from that, or even if a new user clicks on an event, I get that the event was clicked in realtime data but the number of users remain 0 there.

When I add a new user or even from an old user when I click on a button that event is shown here - [GA4 showing event was added in last 30 minutes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR3OZ.png) .
But the Users in last 30 minutes remain 0 like this -
[GA4 showing 0 users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMMeQ.png)